# Whether to use "is" or "are" in a question

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct?

> - Are any of your kids unwell?
> - Is any of your kids unwell?

The online grammar tool shows both as correct, so I am in a dilemma!

Comment: Which "online grammar tool"?

Answer (score -1):

Are any of your kids unwell?
This is the more common usage as 'are' would fit the plural 'kids'.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.